# Chart Js Doughnut chart giving error

Tags: html5-canvas, chart.js

Before I was using chart.js version 1.0.

Now we have updated the js with vesion 2.4.0
But getting following error
[image]

```
 var data = [
{
    value: 20,
    color: "cornflowerblue",
    highlight: "lightskyblue",
    label: "JavaScript"
},
{
    value: 50,
    color: "lightgreen",
    highlight: "yellowgreen",
    label: "HTML"
},
{
    value: 40,
    color: "orange",
    highlight: "darkorange",
    label: "CSS"
}
];
var options = { responsive: true };
var element = component.find('chart').getElement();
var ctx = element.getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);
```

======================

```
  <div onclick="{!c.getChart}"> test
        <canvas aura:id="chart" height="250" width="250"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is different if you are using Chart.js v1 or v2.

And you said you imported the v2 library, but you are still using the v1 syntax with :

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data);
```

---

To fix this, you can change the syntax to the v2's :

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data
});
```

Comment: Hi,

I changed the the syntax as above respective to v2
But I am not able to get the chart.

In console I am getting /resource/ChartJs:4024 Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item